# What is causing this QGIS processing model to fail at r.mapcalculator

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I can't figure this out. I can run a number of tools from the processing toolbox separately with success but when I string them together in a model it keeps failing (image of log below).

It looks like it is falling over at the r.mapcalculator algorithm and some Googling tells me that the error is likely a function or call somewhere that has either failed or returned an unexpected result.

However I am having trouble debugging this problem, this log doesn't tell me too much and the additional logs from the processing toolbox "History and Log" doesn't shed anymore light on the issue because I don't understand what it's saying.

[image: Log from model output]

[image: Log from "History and Log" section of the processing plugin]

[image: Flow of the model]

Comment: I believe what the error is telling you is one of the functions who's output might be an input for another function (or process) is not passing through correctly. The error looks like the second map or raster's extent has not been specified. Judging only by the Log you have displayed, it seems like the layer extent of the second raster is not being input. Could you share a detailed step-by-step method as to what you are trying to achieve? In terms of the application?

Comment: @Akhil thanks for the response. In addition to the log from the model=, I have added the log from the "History and Log" section of the processing plugin. I have also added the flow diagram of my model.

Comment: @Akhil - I think you're right. I redone the model using no clipping and it worked. Then I redone the model using an additional r.mapcalc algorithm with the formaula if(<mask_raster>,<source_raster>) and got the expected results.